# Quotient of a solvable group $G$ of class $\leq n$ is of class $\leq n-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a group. Suppose 
$$H=H_0\supset H_1\supset\ldots\supset H_n=\{e\}$$
is a series of normal subgroups of $H$ such that $H_i/H_{i+1}$ is commutative. Is it true that

> $$D^{n-1}(H/H_{n-1})=\{H_{n-1}\}?$$

**Attempt:**

I know that $H_{n-1}$ is commutative since $H_{n-1}/H_n$ is commutative. This implies that $H_{n-1}$ is a normal commutative subgroup of $H$. I don't know what to do next. Suggestions?